MS Access: Link detail tables to master table and create a corresponding form
I am creating a database of products. Currently, we have one primary table called "Item" and several other tables containing details about specific types of products. For example, think Item, TShirt, Sock, Scarf, etc. Here is the general layout:
|Item
| ID
| Price
| Item code
|TShirt
| ID
| Size
| Style
|Scarf
| ID
| isSilk
| Length
These tables are separated because our database would quickly become a mess if we tracked all attributes on the Item table. We are attempting to use the ID as both a primary key and foreign key, linking each Item to its corresponding product with the ID. For every ID, there should be a total of ONE corresponding record between the different Product tables.
I notice that when I try to create this relationship, Access gives me warnings about referential integrity, and my form doesn't seem to understand my intention. After setting up these relationships, how can I place my product types on a Tab Control so that my user can fill in the Item details, then select the Product type and fill in the corresponding details within the Tab Control for a Product with the same ID?
TL;DR:

Need help setting up the relationships properly
How can I add Product types to a tab control to be used as subforms for Item?


Your question is not about programming but design and responses would be opinions therefore not appropriate for SO. ID (autonumber) in Item table is primary key and ID (long integer not autonumber) would be a foreign key in other tables. Item would be master table bound to a main form and each of the other tables would be subforms on pages of tab control. How do you plan to output this data in report? If you intend to join all child tables to Item, still limited to 255 fields in query. Adding table for each new product is not optimal design.

Now I will get off soap box and confess I have designed a similar database for a laboratory. Tests would equate to your Products - each test is a table. New tests are almost never added. Tests are organized into different categories and reports are based on the categories so not all tests are required for each report. This allows queries joining tables as report RecordSource and very limited need for subreports. The Entity/Attribute/Value data model could be a viable alternative for you. Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables.
